Debugging a Windows Script File *.WSF. Get this error "No disassembly available."
I have a batch file which is supposed to prompt the debugger using  db2cmd cscript //x C:\TEMP\NCANDS.wsf %1%.
But instead of going to my code, I get a disassembly tab labeled "No disassembly available". It doesn't matter whether I select a New Instance or the current instance.
Why?
I have 6 other developers that have the same configuration as I and they are not getting the error running the same script.

How have you validated that the other 6 developers have "the same configuration"?

The only way we can possibly know what is different between running the code on your computer and running it on another developer's computer is for you to figure it out and tell us. We don't have access to those machines.

I ended up downloading the community edition of 2022 version and selecting it instead of our current version.

The error "No disassembly available" typically occurs when debugging a Windows Script File (*.WSF) because the script is interpreted rather than compiled, and debuggers that support disassembly are generally designed for compiled code.

I have 6 other developers that have the same configuration as I and they are not getting the error running the same script.

@Mojoala that should tell you that it's not a software issue but likely a configuration one if it is only affecting you.
